# Node.js flat-cache, when to clear caches

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching

I have a Node.js server which queries MySQL database. It serves as an api end point where it returns JSON and also backend server for my Express application where it returns the retrieved list as an object to the view.

I am looking into implementing [flat-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-cache) for increasing the response time. Below is the code snippet.

```
const flatCache = require('flat-cache');
var cache = flatCache.load('productsCache');

//get all products for the given customer id
router.get('/all/:customer_id', flatCacheMiddleware, function(req, res){
    var customerId = req.params.customer_id;

    //implemented custom handler for querying
    queryHandler.queryRecordsWithParam('select * from products where idCustomers = ? order by CreatedDateTime DESC', customerId, function(err, rows){
        if(err) {
            res.status(500).send(err.message);
            return;
        }
        res.status(200).send(rows);
    });
});

//caching middleware
function flatCacheMiddleware(req, res, next) {
    var key =  '__express__' + req.originalUrl || req.url;
    var cacheContent = cache.getKey(key);
    if(cacheContent){
        res.send(cacheContent);
    } else{
        res.sendResponse = res.send;
        res.send = (body) => {
            cache.setKey(key,body);
            cache.save();
            res.sendResponse(body)
        }
        
        next();
    }
}
```

I ran the node.js server locally and the caching has indeed greatly reduced the response time.

However there are two issues I am facing that I need your help with.

1. Before putting that **flatCacheMiddleware** middleware, I received the response in JSON, now when I test, it sends me an HTML. I am not too well versed with JS strict mode (planning to learn it soon), but I am sure the answer lies in the flatCacheMiddleware function.

So what do I modify in the flatCacheMiddleware function so it would send me JSON?

2. I manually added a new row to the products table for that customer and when I called the end point, it still showed me the old rows. So at what point do I clear the cache?

   In a web app it would ideally be when the user logs out, but if I am using this as an api endpoint (or even on webapp there is no guarantee that the user will log out the traditional way), how do I determine if new records have been added and the cache needs to be cleared.

Appreciate the help. If there are any other node.js caching related suggestions you all can give, it would be truly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. I found a solution to the issue by parsing the content to JSON format.

Change line:

```
res.send(cacheContent);
```

To:

```
res.send(JSON.parse(cacheContent));
```

2. I created cache 'brute force' invalidation method. Calling clear method will clear both cache file and data stored in memory. You have to call it after db change. You can also try delete specified key using `cache.removeKey('key');`.

```js
function clear(req, res, next) {
    try {
        cache.destroy()
    } catch (err) {
        logger.error(`cache invalidation error ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        res.status(500).json({
            'message' : 'cache invalidation error',
            'error' : JSON.stringify(err)
        });
    } finally {
        res.status(200).json({'message' : 'cache invalidated'})
    }
    
}
```

3. Notice, that calling the `cache.save()` function will remove other cached API function. Change it into `cache.save(true)` will 'prevent the removal of non visited keys' (like mentioned in comment in [the flat-cache documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-cache).